# Dynamic td not resize when show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

In the following code clicking the checkbox un-hides a new row in the table, but the cells in that row are not sized the same as those in the first row - how do I ensure the second row has same sized cells?

```js
function test() {
 

 if((document.getElementById("valDesc").classList.contains("tr-withe")) && (document.getElementById("notch").classList.contains("boxNotchNot")) )
 {
 document.getElementById("valDesc").classList.remove('tr-withe');
 document.getElementById("valDesc").classList.add('boxTR');
 document.getElementById("notch").classList.remove("boxNotchNot");
 document.getElementById("notch").classList.add('boxNotchInLine');

 }
 else
 {
 document.getElementById("valDesc").classList.remove('boxTR');
 document.getElementById("valDesc").classList.add('tr-withe');
 document.getElementById("notch").classList.remove("boxNotchInLine");
 document.getElementById("notch").classList.add('boxNotchNot');
 }
}
```

```css
.boxTR
{
 display: block;
 border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
.boxNotchInLine
{

 border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    display: block;
    width: inherit;
}
.boxNotchNot
{
display: none;

}

table {
 
    border-spacing: 0;
    table-layout: fixed; 
 width: auto;
}

th, td {
    text-align: center;
}

.tr-withe
{
 background-color: #E6E6E6
}
.tr-black{
    background-color:#DBDBDB
}
```

```html
<form  action="">
  <table id="testT">
  <tr id="valDesc" class="tr-withe">
   <td>
   ciao
   </td>
   <td>
   <input type="text"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   ciao2
   </td>
   <td>
   ciao3
   </td>
   <td>
   ciao4
   </td>
   
  </tr>
  <tr id="notch" class="boxNotchNot"> 
   <td>
    test
   </td>
   <td > 
    test1
   </td>
   <td > 
    test2
   </td>
   <td > 
    test3
   </td>
   <td > 
    test4
   </td>
   
  </tr>
 
 </table>
 <input type="checkbox" value="" onclick="test()"/>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're killing the table sizing with the `block` display. Comment out in your CSS `display: block` and it will work fine:

```js
function test() {
 if((document.getElementById("valDesc").classList.contains("tr-withe")) && (document.getElementById("notch").classList.contains("boxNotchNot")) )
 {
   document.getElementById("valDesc").classList.remove('tr-withe');
   document.getElementById("valDesc").classList.add('boxTR');
   document.getElementById("notch").classList.remove("boxNotchNot");
   document.getElementById("notch").classList.add('boxNotchInLine');
 }
 else
 {
   document.getElementById("valDesc").classList.remove('boxTR');
   document.getElementById("valDesc").classList.add('tr-withe');
   document.getElementById("notch").classList.remove("boxNotchInLine");
   document.getElementById("notch").classList.add('boxNotchNot');
 }
}
```

```css
.boxTR
{
    !display: block;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
.boxNotchInLine
{
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    !display: block;
    width: inherit;
}
.boxNotchNot
{
display: none;

}

table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    table-layout: fixed; 
    width: auto;
}

th, td {
    text-align: center;
}

.tr-withe
{
 background-color: #E6E6E6
}
.tr-black{
    background-color:#DBDBDB
}
```

```html
<form  action="">
  <table id="testT">
  <tr id="valDesc" class="tr-withe">
   <td>
   ciao
   </td>
   <td>
   <input type="text"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   ciao2
   </td>
   <td>
   ciao3
   </td>
   <td>
   ciao4
   </td>
   
  </tr>
  <tr id="notch" class="boxNotchNot"> 
   <td>
    test
   </td>
   <td style='background-color: red;'> 
    test1
   </td>
   <td > 
    test2
   </td>
   <td > 
    test3
   </td>
   <td > 
    test4
   </td>
   
  </tr>
 
 </table>
 <input type="checkbox" value="" onclick="test()"/>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the css:

```
td{
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

you can get help with this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/20/